# Since 'few' is used for countable nouns and 'less' is for uncountable nouns

Tags: adjectives, uncountable-nouns, descriptive-grammar, countable-nouns

Since 'few' is used for countable things and 'Less' is for uncountable things then why do we say;

> I have less than 2 days/months/years.

?

Yes, time is an uncountable concept but we sure can count days, years, and months...

Comment: When actual days are meant, say "fewer than two days," and when a time span is meant, say "less than two days." HTH.

Comment: Sure, but one hears sentences like 'We have less than a month before the meeting.' So, in theory, they do mean the remaning days, not the time span. Has the miss usage become normalised over time?

Comment: No misuse at all. "Less than a month" is a part of month, not number of days, so not countable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase **two days** as in "two days left" can refer to a *block* of time, that is, to an amount of time remaining, rather than to the *number* of discrete individual days remaining, to their *count*.

We use **few** in situations where the number is relevant, and **less** in situations where the amount of something is remaining.

The semantics of the situation govern here.

Compare:

> Give the child *less mashed potatoes* than you've given me.

Even though the noun "potatoes" is countable, in this context, semantically the reference is to a *serving* of the food, an amount, not a count.

Comment: well, sure potatoes are countable, but not mashed potatoes...

Comment: But the overwhelming majority of native speakers say "mashed potatoes". But the point is, *despite* the countability of **potatoes**, the semantics of the situation govern here.

Comment: well, I assume that is because one often mashes a bunch of potatoes. :)

Comment: The reference is to a serving, an amount, not a number:  *Please give me less peas than you gave  Özgür*.

Comment: Yes, I understand the idea behind food and serving sizes. However, the usage of less when it comes to remaning days that throws me off.

Comment: The reference is to an *amount* of time.  *Only five days until summer vacation! But I wish it was even less!*

Comment: So, grammatically speaking, one could both say "he is going to be here in less than five days' and 'he is going to be here fewer than two days' depending on what they want to emphasise?

Comment: Yes. That's the beauty of language. It reveals thought.  It is expressive. But we cannot say *He will be visiting for **fewer** than a week.* Plural units like seconds, minutes, days, months can express an amount of time, but singular units cannot be cast into the units they comprise.

Comment: @ÖzgürAkyıldız Think of it as "_I have less than 2 days/months/years **worth of time**_".  "_2 days_" is _measuring_ (not counting) the amount of the (uncountable) thing called time.

Answer (score 2):

TRomano's answer (and comments) explains everything quite correctly; however, we can also say ***in a few days' time*** as in

> *I'm going to have an exam in a few days' time*

and in the following

> *May I ask a few questions?*

substituting *few* with *less* would be incorrect. In this instance, "a few" is closer in meaning to "some".

Answer (score 2):

As you adequately state it, the period can be considered both an uncountable chunk of time (as in the example you provide) or in relation to its individual units (hours, days). That's why

> I have less than 2 days/months/years.

is correct. A similar use often occurs with money.

> The new model costs less than ten pounds.

Regardless, we should also consider that for most native speakers *fewer than* would sound **more formal** than *less than*, which explains a higher occurence of the latter.

[image: Ngram for 'fewer than' v 'less than']

- Further details on this topic can be found in [Cambridge Dictionary's
  blog entry by Liz Walter](https://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/2014/05/28/less-or-fewer/).
- [Ngram shown here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fewer%20than%2Cless%20than&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfewer%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cless%20than%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfewer%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cless%20than%3B%2Cc0).